# Ratio between training error and validation error

Tags: machine-learning, cross-validation

I know that we should choose the model which minimizes validation error. But is there any meaning of ratio between training error and validation error?

[image]

I was wondering if it tells something about the complexity of the model?

Answer (score 1):

The interpretation of such a ratio would be:

- r = 100% ... same error for both validation and training
- r $<$100% ...worse error for the validation
- r > 100% ... (unusual) validation error better than the training error

As you can see from your picture, this ratio decreases all the time and from the breakpoint significantly faster. However,  it is not able to provide the same information about the quality of the training as both original curves. Moreover, the ratio does not provide any information about the achieved error of the models.

Conclusion: the ratio could be used for some visualization of the training dynamics, but can be hardly used for the decision about termination of learning.